# got two different answers for a derivative.

Tags: calculus

The homework problem. **I have the answer sheet**

> $ f\left( x \right) = \left(x-1 \right)^2 \left(x+3\right)$

$f^{\prime}\left(x\right) = 2\left(x-1\right)\left(x+3\right) + \left(x-1\right)^2$

I got $\left(x-1\right)\left(3x+5\right)$

The answer sheet gives $\left(x-1\right)\left(x+5/3\right)$

when I plot them in wolframalpha, i get two different graphs with the same $x$-intercepts.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: so the answer sheet just happens to have another function with the correct roots for the problem?

Comment: @njguliyev, derivatives are unique?

Comment: Yes, they are unique.

Comment: Maybe a factor 3 didn't get through the printer.

Comment: Maybe the typist was typing too fast like 200wpm thus missed a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  The book answer is $\frac 13$ of yours for reasons unknown.

Comment: lot of math is for reasons unknown.